# How to select nested xml nodes into Model

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML document:

```
<Preferences>
    <Section Name="PREF_SECTION_NAME_1">
        <Preference Name="PREF_NOTIFY" Type="radio">
            <Options>
                <Option Name="PREF_OPT_YES" Value="true"/>
                <Option Name="PREF_OPT_NO" Value="false"/>
            </Options>
            <Default>true</Default>
       </Preference>
       <Preference Name="PREF_EXAMPLE" Type="textarea" >
           <Default>lots and lots of lines of text"</Default>
       </Preference> 
   </Section>
</Preferences>
```

This my Model:

```
[XmlRoot("Preferences")]
public class PreferencesModel
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Section")]
    public List<Section> Section { get; set; }
}

public class Section
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Preference")]
    public List<PreferenceModel> PreferenceModel { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("Preference")]
public class PreferenceModel
{
    [XmlAttribute("Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Default")]
    public string Default { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Options")]
    public List<Option> Options { get; set; }
}

[XmlAttribute("Name")]
[XmlType("Option")]
public class Option
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I use XDocument to make this XML data accessible via Linq:

My Method to XML to Model:

```
public PreferencesModel GetDefaults(XmlDocument userDoc)
{
    XDocument xDocUser = userDoc.ToXDocument();

    return new PreferencesModel()
    {
        Section = xDocUser.Root.Elements("Section").Select(x => new Section()
        {
            Name = x.Attribute("Name").Value,
            PreferenceModel = x.Elements("Preference").Select(
            y => new PreferenceModel()
            {
                Name = y.Attribute("Name").Value,
                Default = (string)y.Element("Default").Value,
                Type = y.Attribute("Type").Value,
                Options = y.Elements("Options").Select(z => new Option()
                {
                    Name = z.Attribute("Name").Value,
                    Value = z.Attribute("Value").Value
                }).ToList(),
            }).ToList(),
        }).ToList()
    };
}
```

and when i run I get this:

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest to use XmlSerialization/deserialization.

Comment: @MaciejLos Not option for me here

Comment: Change "Options" to "Option".  Options does not have any attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your context, `y` is the element `Preference`.  You then select all its child `Options` elements and get their `Name` and `Value` attributes.

`Options` doesn't have any attributes, it only has child `Option` elements.

Your `Options` selector should be:

```
y.Descendants("Option").Select(z => new Option
{
    Name = (string)z.Attribute("Name"),
    Value = (string)z.Attribute("Value")
}
```

Note that I've also used the explicit conversions from `XAttribute` to `string` here. This has the advantage of returning `null` if the attribute doesn't exist rather than throwing a `NullReferenceException`.

However... why not use the `XmlSerializer` given you've marked everything up with attributes already?

Comment: Charles, thanks for your answer.  I keep forgetting about Descendants!  The code  I am working on is just a small part of a huge process.  Just picking up stuff here :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply deserializing your XML will give you expected result:

```
using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PreferencesModel));
    var data = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```